# read-only variable from string is not assignable in for-loop C

Tags: c, string, for-loop, constants

The program gets a string from input and looks for the n'th char in the string in a other inputted string. If the first char from the first string is in the second string the program will output the char if not it will print no char match. The programs looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    const char s[1000], i;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", s);

    const char str1[1000];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);

    // int b;

    for(i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        b = i;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < b; i++){
        char *ret;
        ret = strpbrk(s, s[i]);
        if(ret)
        {
            printf("First matching character: %c\n", *ret);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no char match \n");
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The error is in the both of the for-loops and states:

> error: read-only variable not assignable

Furthermore an error states:

> note: passing argument to parameter here

Comment: Don't use `const` if you want to be able to assign to variables...

Comment: If you declare `s` and `str1` as `const char` arrays, you cannot modify the values (they're only meaningful, in fact, if you provide an initializer).  Simply remove the `const`! And using `const char i` as a loop index to work over an array of size up to 1000 has all sorts of problems too.  You can't modify it; it won't hold all the values you need.

Comment: Why do you use `const`?

Answer (score 3):

You have got problems *far before* the `for` loop.

```
 scanf("%s", s);
 scanf("%s", str1);
```

and obviously

```
for ( i = 0; ...; ++i
```

are invalid, as you're trying to write into  (*i.e., modify the contents of*) *objects* defined with `const` type qualifier. They are supposed to behave as *constants*, i.e., the values are not supposed to be changed, so they cannot be changed or altered, only can be initialized.

The fix: remove `const` from the two sets of variable definitions.